# Are there any other services that can be used for FB App development except for Heroku, for free?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm really not sure if I should deploy it on Heroku since it will involve learning using git commands to work with remote servers and so am looking for alternatives. Preferably somewhere where I can pull/push files using FTP

Comment: I would advise that using git was the best option. It is very simple, fast and secure to use once you're used to it. To get stuff into Heroku, you only need to know how to commit and push.

Though if you're adamant about not using Heroku, you can host anywhere which can run whatever language your app back-end is written in. For PHP, as one example, there are hundreds/thousands of free hosting companies. The first one which springs to mind is 000webhost. Reliability isn't amazing on free hosting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing magical required of a hosting platform to be able to deploy a server-side Facebook app. Heroku is great and easy, but any platform that runs PHP (for example) would be viable.

But don't forget that you can also create a Facebook app with client-side HTML5 & JavaScript. In that scenario, (in the extreme) your host merely needs to serve up static files.

And finally, you can get a long way on a local developer machine. The main challenge is Open Graph objects (which must be visible to the outside world), but otherwise quite viable